# Correct use of React fragments with array of elements in React 16

Tags: reactjs, jsx

`headTags` is an array of React elements without any keys defined. I am able to render without warnings using the following JSX.

```
return (
  <head>
    {React.Children.toArray(headTags)}
  </head>
);
```

Is there some possible way to do this with fragments in React 16? I get a warning that a `key` is required for each child element when using this:

```
return (
  <head>
    <React.Fragment>
      {headTags}
    </React.Fragment>
  </head>
);
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [this answer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12776#issuecomment-410183724) in github issue you can.

Render array of items **without keys** by making them **just as children** within `React.Fragment` or any element using [React.createElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)

**Problem:** itemsArray is an array hence expects key

```
render() {
  return <React.Fragment>{...itemsArray}</React.Fragment>
}
```

**Solution:** itemsArray is exploded directly as children hence no key needed

```
render() {
  return React.createElement(React.Fragment, {}, ...itemsArray)
}
```

This represents the below

```
render() {
  return <React.Fragment>
    <YourItem />
    <YourItem />
    <YourItem />
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`React.Fragment` is an alternative to rendering arrays and you don't need a key if you have render multiple elements with `React.Fragment`

```
return (
  <head>
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>Here</div>
      <div>And HEre</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  </head>
);
```

However anytime you need to render an array of elements you need to specify a key. You can avoid the warning if you specify a key on each element in the array(a unique key will improve optimisation) or using `React.Children.toArray()` which adds a key if not present but is not optimum